# The image MIME type is not valid

Tags: api

i'm using magento api, and have an error:
`{"message":"The image MIME type is not valid or not supported."}`

Request:

```
POST
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer cz3p4vxgbrxcz5uct6rl9m0q8o66rwix
{"entry":{"media_type":"image","label":"jajko","position":0,"disabled":false,"types":["image","small_image","thumbnail","swatch_image"],"file":"/j/a/jajko.jpg","content":{"base64_encoded_data":"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","type":"image/jpeg","name":"jajko.jpg"}}}
```

Despite the correct mime type ==> "image / jpeg" I gets a message that it is incorrect.
Photo in the attachment.

Thanks

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

Update **type** attribute in your JSON to **image/png** and try again.

```
{
  "entry": {
    "media_type": "image",
    "label": "jajko",
    "position": 0,
    "disabled": false,
    "types": [
      "image",
      "small_image",
      "thumbnail",
      "swatch_image"
    ],
    "file": "/j/a/jajko.png",
    "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMcAAACcCAMAAAD8kk/AAAACQFBMVEX////wTiPsTCT3+Pjl5eTT09P19fXMy8vb29rw7+/Q0NDkSCXHxsbdRCbe3t3IPSbNPya9vb3TQibAOiavr6+VlZW5NibYQyYAAAC2tregoKCtMCSOjo7wQQCnp6fydVzwRhTvLwD/9/WRIR6aJiCDy/T1k4UAAxj5wLf2n5Pzf2j2nIv3raDk7OyMAACoAAAAk9MArPIAyv/f9P3z///6z8jG6Pv72NPjOQCn2ffU7v0vsfBEuvGV1fZiwvMAo+0mJiY0NDR5e31CT1HXnpX96+YRFCDyaFDzgnXisaseIipubm70i3bxYkTwEwBDREfwTziMnrUngLopcqR+i5u2oKFmpMrk4tVvAACsrroAZqZZc4GjdYmzAFrUAG2gAFYAPHUATYq2rISwmkG/pACtf3vIAABAAACbHQBkgT+Ak2NEY3dWlKk+MkKDQDyquKG0xZvFyLikQHv/F5u+AG0Ahixvq3v70QD/4gBqZS+ramPDVSNsWFqfyRyOpCUxiZUWns92m5IZACpgMCyBiSkAS2YAgqznuRibdDfKF4bkQZUAZBYdylIxbXuwoCFTPR3O6CxdY0eMkQAjAB6bOACtsBBIPgC9iwBoH0kmOy8/jz1Nu0kKblaVghdfGyXfJSXFaz8iOkmeQSOHUyuCfFXNaJ0rW1X+6EP9eDzJhEmxvlnCuXeTTXFNhRyNgTbu9hR3xUNbbA5EKSbOoECwXkkAhtaAsLz8sgrikwBtQ1xtqkN8rh9DSyNqhgC/TkqYOjg4Riw5AAAM6UlEQVR4nO2bi1ta5x3HD5wjcAS5yAGV6wEVQSFABCECGlGKFpnG22LMui4xzjb2kmUdFaOlaxuSLBfsZu3qsnSt2ZK0s5ckpms786/tfc85XL2ue+I5eXa+iQ/hgI+/z/P93d6DQRBevHjx4sWLFy9evHjx4sWLFy9evHjx4sWLF6/DkQjHcQzDcBxlO5L/QSJAgMmBJJKq6iqM7XB+onC5nHICwmASSbVMJWE7pJ8gOpsYQVuAJTKZXMR2XP+dUJymEAHRHBSIWCZ7rrJLBCBENAVNQqdWlRiAVLEd3MFVJBChJY5IqoAjYpXsecmtAgYKVQSBmQVAZCqc7QgPJAxnAFBGFAde5JCpnoMiQXEGo8iBlhoihiAN3Hck7wYl6gqdW7QhEppDRnAdhHIDoYIvbCJFRwqGqDjuCMTYfpUBKbQsyKHictcS7YgBQRiOEkNk3N0cRZgI3Tm6IkjeEBXB3YGI7WIHnVkVvVfF2VrfuTho5Q2hVvhqiqNBxc3MwjF8l6xCKiqEASGqDzO8gwrF8N2qg3q5YEiBo4Hg4lzHdy1ySiUczJYFOFSHF96BtbcdZR2rAKKTH158BxS2V3Ug+Y5FFwjde6EhukOL74ASyfe2o8SQfGJBEBPXSh3bq+lSKnLQIDI41AmCW+uJaPcRmFclB7WcECZuTXVsfw6kZIIUW6+JU1Mdle+bVgwHni/0fGLpuHRTC5Pvj4GUrFgliaUzHUaAB5TkAHaUcJQUSANh4E5i4TCt9n1XYaLLSzsvoSMOIcKDSX6AKi/6UZyEFIdJw5XWi+/frXzHIkjxlA5Xk/xIB4aIDynO/bQ3BtreGQl5m70lp/RyQzQcSSx0L472Y81hb3PkWLO3HangKOxYOm6s77h8jxWx2dt8LBLpCnWFd0wsajXRcGOm43sNj0hzOBQKd0WaI+GK1aRwvCU0DVw44KJ7dquO7lAk0tHc3BXqyN/HyicWAGE6LydGCMVR8rxKYyp52hkKRcJdzZEOH0L7UbjbkDcEdF4DFwpEJCm3g6g/XhKWLxw+1tHpY56V3DWhWxa9Kxq4cL6t3K2Ilh4ciR7v7ROaYwgMnb7cRjqQws4rZwyBHQtOQg0LcVdKgm3n0NS/IPbH+63gqZW6aEVsFht8RH1ghXG5aA7akAaTLspG4BUCHGVVDjh0x+sJxD/osDucDpsjhgQc/Y5Wow08Drb5Ub/D6RwoJJaKIwUikmCiCo4XXqxPIIjdYh40GkmjpS2QtCQFpNEBHoeNArvTaPxZP1aWWAYZW+EXhMm3c7S01KOI3Wi2kXHEAR4srYg1abS1GtusAYu5TZDEXHSlw45FFQj7h5Bt04NoaRkaqjfkOZxkfNBiRxAz2RonSYtFGB8UmF0lHUulIggd+4UuwSqOHkTL8SpNS4+8wGGmSjxpHDSTgwF7m9NBQg7GEDqxdKzv7uh2jvoeHDterwMcg5DD2OonScBgdNgtSZuZdDiNgAPLc9CHWw3bhY5XljmiGkrgiGmoty/e70j2I07w5Y8Pm1uTDsSfHB52+OzJfoZDQq8mcDNhe1XEK9vuzrIyjzE4GH1wFjKjsIrOK9YbFgb8AGEhuOqgvwEDl8UqguKQS2SEiRubCeBAT4yMNpzwjIyhCE4xQYkwpmpQuYv5GF0WBZdAEkqqxuuOiKEjk6MjnlETNIR9DrkIm/B6dBPdI5qfE0fcbvdJOYJMjp46dWoKGISe/sVLL/1yHK2WiF7u/pX4zNnp3nMzvx4Pzja88iqB6TzekPe8GHKwe7a1Qg7JRCg0NuGdm55+TSEVSl9/480LY95QKJQZk1y48JuLQL81vPXW70a9o4ZU6u35tGDhkmAhuriYeGPpnXAmPEqf0Vk+SsnloqpMt+eGp/vdVOr3ioX33ptfXFx8Pxz+4HJo4mw2e+XqtavXLv7h+vXrN7ovJ96eTt18XSi9VbPQk1taXsx9+M6No0cTYm5wVI889lwe8bz7JPXHuj9J3szlllY+ymR0unBmNZVKpT8mTl/98s+frP3lsefW27ezqb/eufOpIj6fW1nMrfSG/5YJ3WgAHCb2OWQj3Z6Mh+ZY+OzzpW/GxqozmamJ8NztxHrq9seuhqt33/1k7e/dmfnUxpXslTvJugXzUi6XWxnKHB2a83ZFVUTZGZIdDnzyVMgD/ixn/3F84d69+0u5Bw++uAESv2t5Xi6fnv5SJrt29621f055PBvZjfXU2Tv37wybVxYXcwkic7R3LhQea+AEx4nHXZc9nq4fV1ND9z6/9e2HXwHd9Bzt6l09I8IBByG7enrt6+VqT2g+m80+uam9/0iozwGOqerM0XA4FJrTcCGvsBOPN0cBx/LD1K17t1zo5NDGUu6rD+YSG9kzogup23cTdy9+//U3mPxU+NaT7IPVh9r73w7rcysri2eBH5HmSChjYL/OwfFj7vHmea9nM/rwyXrys0fp9QeTuqXc+cuS9ezNC6vZjWvXLqavf/+qqupUeCg7P7ax+qmjJ31lcen9xZVoV7g3cSkcnjKxzCHyBwBH6MSY5/GmDnD097favsi98uCH3Ms3VFWrT757svKvi9fufr+2tvbD0Pm5nu9eFZ3Jrid0k0uLSwnQnjMhjVg2553QsHyP12rpk2OJ8y/K5pqnZA9TP14CGloCA+RHU7UIOTOdXUkYTr+WWF76eu3fJlnDzZvrOPFRjwSVzK+cnXyQ+/Cyd5OQRCNTvbpx6/4/7RlyGAGHCBfh0UQUNSQaqIuTy+sJqvugk+d1YL8C/xJHN8CJHYlGwRqFwZs/VWMa3DA0trk5Z6omLmkIQ9rJIgaCDDsqj+dQO/RQrPgm+HkOvbljhEEjg78+qhnTmp9pnPvJ3Jq/fYW2A/l8+34HfS+O+t8Ucgn4Cw9SxObrM4PPOtQ91WYWY/D3fHztnZ2dPvQAnxJCjvb2znZw+qA/KARr+2b0SJDdvLIbxXIX3t7e0dnRLnG4Z2aS/vI3oKW/AEtfAcgdnRKxWEKdCMUyYtPQqA/aDzHq7fJbxjuAOjvbxefUQaFAQMaLjcfnc8FU85Vlm6uzo8M1fm4rOJOG9+KqAYbmaZOeDBx+8CUKkIpJUBeSvrRWCigEAmNr4TVYL4g1MJBO29IDhYvAuPGt2iB4qwXaISNU40/1TdpkjJX484qZpYrZ2Vl3nVRAK5l/BVC4rH2KGamABLLQ6Y8CM/B0Df1Wo6MdFIfs3Kxe31jXyur8QKw2Ul1bJ5UKhUxsVLw+UPftqLhPHWToQMwIXRmugS3molBA9qmI8aezWq2+kfpQgU05AUdNkYOMIz6qAaN+hzJoBFeNw0b4gt8Hrnf6xOkZYZ5NKAhq9W61Wq1vahSwW+ag0IUKZV0piM0K6ts6AEqAJO3WJPhyAhBhAGD4rOf0+fyDHFJpTW2tAnA06lkuD5BYcWmZIQKjxW12z4DcMcZjSGDGhvjkQeiTP+ZPu4WCEgyhtIbiAOVR07r/T3rGspUnFuUJnWFWn+8R6fT5BmBBkMaZYCkFbUddrVKtBWnF8hSECliUCpBYQmF5lGQygPhEW6TNJVOUv0J7ASSVAgwF5NBa2O1WlAQ12wyBHE44B7dIwXBdJYZQyGDU1CqBHVpOpBXoWEGForamgoMa6z6fjdxmhSBPQWUVZYc+yO4wpxUTKGmOUhASfjiL+gaMu6UUqPE6yg5Q5UozB9IKVHpQq6yrSCxqroES3+4HTUFh1CooO5pY3hHzCgjVCgqklKMVju8dOJjKoN2As0PfqDazPTwY2Ui9otIQoR0MPmxrZwzaDVgcsOmS7DddWgGBcltmkVKHvW9LujNHHoOaHYokJ6oDajCoVW9vWYJgJYWg2KmorIJF3mThQrNiRNZplXWVIDuoaAfAUAAMMMrZPZiXy09qtcrtw3AHDCkzOOgab2pUxzlS5JSstqBescNU3xMD2tEk5UbPzSsWr9Er9wYRFiYHlVR0rwq2sR15hQJCpXYvR4TCkgGYd6MxyIXFqlx2Uq1lHKkgEZbsVOUYbm4sJOVywlqvrQEk5SjCIgSkYDC0FAaXarwgJ6nX0odcKRX5DhRMiWspDDXrh9ldZBdo9WplbZGkhIGiKOYUwFDGOZhUtOxJpR7ujHVUdpUIPGfMUOYxamwcdQMqEA82aRUKWCZFlBraCYqCmn6AApzIOesGJZtUDywBJCC9CqqthftUcfiB0uDQUrWz/Ga3Xq8F2aWoLQiMPQVIKNilIMWs2sFtMyjF7PGZJkACXClIzUBAiiMzbZw3g1bMSbob9aC5qvOiGABE08mTM4OB58CMvPzmLf2svklfEDCi8cjJp+bnIaPKFLM7Hm253bNHGLn1j9JO//7fx0HFAv6Bvj6b7ZGtr2/AH4g9b1aUywrEdgy8ePHixYsXL168ePHixYsXL17/f/oPbXVb9uxrCcYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
      "type": "image/png",
      "name": "jajko.png"
    }
  }
}
```